# Why was there no purely human council?

Tags: mass-effect-series

Wasn't there supposed to be the possibility of having a human only council?

In the case where you let the council die and were fully renegade: Udina suggests, and you can support him, to form a council made only of human members as you can hear [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hHo-mbB_Ug&feature=related) in Mass Effect?

Is there any explanation for why this doesn't happen, or is it just that the writers dropped this possibility?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was never supposed to be an entirely human council. It is true that Udina suggests that at the end of ME1 but a human-only council is never confirmed to have been a fact in subsequent games. If you let the old council die, the new one will be led by humans but won't be purely human. That's how the council is presented in ME2 no matter what Udina says at the end of ME1.

As for an explanation why exactly the Udina suggestion fails - none is given in the games. We can only speculate that such total control was simply not allowed by the other races in the galaxy.

Comment: Also, the epilogue takes place after the final save is made for ME1, which is why Miranda has to ask who you chose as councilor at the beginning of ME2. I don't recall if you can protest the all-human council idea, but even if you could, that choice would not be represented in the imported ME1 save.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a purely human council, but you can get one that is mostly human controlled.